# Why implement IDisposable if database connection is created in a "using" block?

Tags: c#, connection, database-connection, dispose, idisposable

Seems like "using" block handles disposing a database connection without the need to implement IDisposable, so why do I have to implement IDisposable?

```
using (var con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
  // blah
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because the _using_ directive calls the Dispose method when exiting from the block?

Comment: Let's start with why you think you might need to implement `IDisposable`. You haven't provided any context where you *could* implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: OracleConnection does indeed implement IDisposable, not sure what you mean that YOU have to implement it..  `OracleConnection` extends `DbConnection` the signature of which is..  `public abstract class DbConnection : System.ComponentModel.Component, IAsyncDisposable, IDisposable, System.Data.IDbConnection`

Comment: hijinxbassist -- Ah, you just opened my eyes to the answer - OracleConnction extends IDisposable eventually which will eventually call Dispose or the finalizer. I'm saying this because I noticed "using" by itself, without Dispose, was disposing the connection and I couldn't figure out how. So when using "using", there is no need to implement IDisposable.  You answer is what I was looking for; than you!